# How to do complex forms with jQuery instead of RJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rjs, railscasts

In episode 74 of railscasts ryan shows how to achieve complex forms with RJS: http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2

The trick is to create a partial and `link_to` the partial using RJS.  The episode is quite old and at that time probably jQuery was not around.  Now with my Rails3 app I want to achieve the same thing as he does in episode 74 but I want achieve the same thing using jQuery instead.

Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you may want to checkout some new railscasts from Ryan Bates.

This one in special that achieves what you want to do but using Prototype and jQuery as well.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: both parts of that series are great.